# Getting Error for PGSQL "ERROR: syntax error at or near "where""

Tags: postgresql

Help!! I am new to SQL and I am getting the error for the below query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actor;
WHERE first_name LIKE '%P';
```

ERROR:  `syntax error at or near "where" LINE 2:  where first_name LIKE '%P'`;

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra semicolon before the "WHERE"

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actor WHERE first_name LIKE '%P';
```